# How to type purely functional React wrapper component with access to children

Tags: reactjs, typescript

With the introduction of React Hooks, the creators of React recommend using function components in the future.

However, I wonder how to define and type the component's properties when I want to access children components. I have come up with this solution:

```
import * as React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

type MyWrapperCompProps = {
  color: string;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
};

function MyWrapperComp(props: MyWrapperCompProps) {
  return <div style={{ backgroundColor: props.color }}>{props.children}</div>;
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MyWrapperComp color="tan">
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro, fuga.
        </p>
      </MyWrapperComp>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit distracted-sunset-qgwpo]

This seems to work, but I have a couple of questions:

1. Is this the best practice to model wrapper components?
2. Is `ReactNode` the correct type for `children`?
3. How does React automagically know that the children are assigned to `props.children`?
4. Is the above documented anywhere at all on the React website?